# Where do I ask a question about methods of development that includes the law?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I have a question on if an idea I want to develop could have legal troubles, but I also want to get suggestions on how to get around it, or avoid them. It's a combination of web development and law, so do I just post it in Law? Or am I allowed to post in Web Applications?

Answer (score 2):

No. Not Web Apps. Web Apps is meant for people who *use* web based software not people who *write* it.

If you're worried about actual legal trouble I wouldn't rely on a bunch of random people who claim to be experts on the internet. Even says so on the <strike>tin</strike> sidebar

> Law Stack Exchange is for educational purposes only and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner. Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship.

Under "[asking](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"

> Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter. These are off-topic for Law Stack Exchange. While users generally contribute answers in good faith, the answers are not legal advice, and contributors here are not your lawyer.

If it's *serious*, go talk to a lawyer.

With more detail, we can maybe find something - but if you're asking 'should I ask a development related question on Web Apps' - have a look at the site help to see if it's in scope.

Comment: well its a site where you rate people at my college campus , so it would be like 'if i created this , could there be legal issues , and what methods could i use to avoid them' , like no pictures of people , or no real names or something

Comment: That's one of those things where you *really* want someone familiar with local laws and culture taking a look.